# Enum Generic Abstract Class Constructor

Tags: java, generics, enums, constructor, abstract

Eclipse reported the error that "Change constructor 'MyEnum(Class`<AbstractIO>`) to MyEnum(Class`<StringIO>`)'" in MyEnum.java.

How to fix it for using both(StringIO and NumberIO)?

AbstractIO.java

```
public class AbstractIO{}
```

StringIO.java

```
public class StringIO extends AbstractIO{}
```

NumberIO.java

```
public class NumberIO extends AbstractIO{}
```

MyEnum.java

```
public enum MyEnum {
    String ( StringIO.class),
    Number( NumberIO.class);

    private Class<AbstractIO> ioClass;

    MyEnum( Class<AbstractIO> clazz) {
        this.ioClass = clazz;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. I need it.

Comment: The type you need for a reference to a class that extends `AbstractIO` is `Class<? extends AbstractIO>`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable of type `Class<AbstractIO>`, the only class you can set it to is `AbstractIO.class`.

The type you need for a reference to a class that extends `AbstractIO` is `Class<? extends AbstractIO>`.

```
public enum MyEnum {
    String(StringIO.class),
    Number(NumberIO.class);

    private Class<? extends AbstractIO> ioClass;

    MyEnum(Class<? extends AbstractIO> clazz) {
        this.ioClass = clazz;
    }
}
```